# How to push only the elements not found in my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

So the question is asking me to remove punctuation from my word and i know how to cross-reference the tho arrays to check if an element exists in my array to be checked but how do i only push the values that are not in my punctuation array?

```
function removePunctuation(word){
  var punctuation = [";", "!", ".", "?", ",", "-"];
  var chars = word.split("");
  var puncRemoved = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < chars.length;i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < punctuation.length;j++) {
      if(punctuation[j].indexOf(chars[i]) !== 0) {
        puncRemoved.push(i)
      }
    }
  }
  return puncRemoved;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
word.replace(/[;\!\.\?\,-]/g, '');
```

You might find [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4838/most-complex-hello-world-program-you-can-justify) very interesting :D

Comment: Cool, but the OP also needs an answer the their question: "*…how do i only push the values that are not in my punctuation array?*"

Comment: @RobG well in this case the answer is as simple as it gets - you don't. :P

Comment: Then this isn't an answer.

Comment: @RobG huh, then what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which is based on your code:

```
function removePunctuation(word){
  var punctuation = [";", "!", ".", "?", ",", "-"];
  var chars = word.split("");
  var puncRemoved = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {

    // Push only chars which are not in punctuation array
    if (punctuation.indexOf(chars[i]) === -1) {
        puncRemoved.push(chars[i]);
    }
  }

  // Return string instead of array
  return puncRemoved.join('');
}
```

Another way to implement this would be:

```
function removePunctuation(word){
  var punctuation = [";", "!", ".", "?", ",", "-"];

  // Iterate and remove punctuations from the given string using split().join() method
  punctuation.forEach(function (p) {
    word = word.split(p).join('');
  });

  return word;
}
```

Or, as suggested in another answer:

```
function removePunctuation(word){
    return word.replace(/[;\!\.\?\,-]/g, '');
}
```

Comment: i love this website so simple but makes so much sense thnx man

Comment: Also with index of you dont have to go through the array for it to check if the property your checking for is in the array being iterated through?

Comment: @JusticeNelson that's correct, although as for runtime there is no difference since `indexOf()` time complexity is still O(n).

Answer (score 0):

You need to *push* the value when it's not found in the array, so:

```
punctuation.indexOf(chars[i]) == -1
```

but a regular expression seems so much simpler.

#### Edit

To make it clear, you need to iterate over the characters and only push them if they don't appear in the punctuation array:

```js
function removePunctuation(word){
  var punctuation = [";", "!", ".", "?", ",", "-"];
  var chars = word.split("");
  var puncRemoved = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < chars.length;i++){
    if(punctuation.indexOf(chars[i]) == -1) {
      puncRemoved.push(chars[i])
    }
  }
  return puncRemoved;
}

var s = 'Hi! there. Are? you; ha-ppy?';
console.log(removePunctuation(s).join(''))
```

Comment: but then it pushes it every iteration i only want to push it once